# How do you specify the label (y) in Java Spark ML?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

For instance here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression

They just have

```
Dataset<Row> training = spark.read().format("libsvm")
  .load("data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt");

LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8);

// Fit the model.
LinearRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit(training);
```

But say you have a .csv file with 10 columns loaded by

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().csv(logFile);
```

Then how can you specify that the .csv's 6th column is the (y) label variable before feeding it to the `lr.fit(training)`?
This is on Apache Spark 2.1.1

Thanks!